# How to fetch Custome Ads through AdMob?

Tags: admob

Problem Statment:

1. I have a tempalate ad and there are follwoing supported files inside it.

   .HTML
   .JS
   .CSS
2. Created Intrestitial Ads through House ads on AdMob dashboard :  https://apps.admob.com/#home

   > Steps performed:
   >       .Successfully created ads through Monetize and Campiagns sections.
   >       .Checked the Preview Ads and my add is getting fetched.
   >       .Copy the App ID and Ad unit ID
3. The ad is getting Disapproved because of Adsense policy for Google.

Can anyone suggest, what settings I need to do so that my ads gets approved. Secondly, if not then is there any way by which we can show are custom ads through AdMob.

**Note:** This is my test app.

Please can anyone suggest on this.

Answer (score 0):

Use NativeAds to support your color design.

https://developers.google.com/admob/android/native